# Ubuntu won't load. Only shows terminal

Tags: boot, python3

I uninstalled python3.8 and I think it broke Ubuntu. Now I can only see a very simplistic version of the terminal:

[image]

How would I recover from this?

Comment: That is the ubuntu command line interface. If all that you did was uninstall python3.8 then you could try reinstalling it with  `sudo apt-get install python3` and reboot.

Comment: Try `sudo apt update`, then  `sudo apt install ubuntu-gnome-desktop -y`. When done, reboot. If that does not help you're looking at a re-install. In future take an image of your system, each month.

Comment: Many Ubuntu tools are reliant on the `python` that comes with the system, so if you remove that essential tool, you'll lose the ability to run every feature that required/used it.  Your Ubuntu base is still good, but as many end-user tools/featuers required python those are gone. The essential tool needed is `python3-minimal` which may need to be installed via `wget` & `dpkg` but it'll depend how much of required python3 you removed...

Comment: I just uninstalled and reinstalled Ubuntu entirely. Thanks everyone for your help!